# Reading textbox input and putting in one of two boxes javascript

Tags: javascript, textbox

I am trying to allow the user to enter 1 letter in a text box, and then the letters gets put into 1 of 2 boxes. This is for a hangman game, so it is going to divide the letters based on whether or not it is in the word. Here's my code. Hopefully someone can help me. I'm new to javascript! I've done a ton of googling, but to little avail.

```
var words = ['dog', 'computer', 'cat', 'monkey', 'human'];

var wordForGuess = chooseWord();

var wordLength = wordForGuess.length;

function chooseWord () {
  return words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
}

function writeWord()
{
  var textarea = document.getElementById('textBox').value;

  for (var x = 0; x<wordLength; x++)
  {
    if (textarea === wordForGuess.indexOf(x))
    {
      document.getElementById('correctLetters').value = textarea;
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById('incorrectLetters').value = textarea;
    }
  }
}
```

As well as the HTML for my textbox

```
<div id = 'letterInput'>
</div>

<input type = 'text' id = 'textBox' onkeyUp="writeWord()"/>

<div id = 'correctLetters'>
</div>

<div id = 'incorrectLetters'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few mistakes, including iterating over your characters in your chosen word and using the index of that iteration instead of just checking the value from the input box. I also think you should reset the value on each keyup. I also moved your onkeyup event out of the HTML into JavaScript, I think maybe in your case the JavaScript hadn't loaded yet but it's hard to tell from your example.

```
<div id = 'letterInput'>
    </div>
    <input type = 'text' id = 'textBox' />
<br/>
Correct:
<div id = 'correctLetters'>

    </div>
<br/>
Incorrect
    <div id = 'incorrectLetters'>

    </div>
```

Here's the JavaScript with some fixes:

```
var words = ['dog', 'computer', 'cat', 'monkey', 'human'];

var wordForGuess = chooseWord();

var wordLength = wordForGuess.length;

function chooseWord () {
  return words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
}

function writeWord() {
  var input, textarea;

    input = document.getElementById('textBox')
    textarea = input.value;
    input.value = "";
    console.log("writing word", textarea);

    if (wordForGuess.indexOf(textarea) !== -1) {
        document.getElementById('correctLetters').innerText += textarea;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('incorrectLetters').innerText += textarea;
    }
}

document.getElementById("textBox").onkeyup = writeWord;
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btipling/LewaLs9o/) with this code.